# Is it possible to create user-defined snippets in TikzEdt?

Tags: editors

Is it possible to create user-defined snippets in TikzEdt? http://www.tikzedt.org/

If it is possible, how do I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to `Settings` → `Snippet Manager`. A window opens. In this select New Snippet (1) and fill in the details and you have to compile and save afterwards.

[image]

The snippet is then visible:

[image]